# Netsuite form JavaScript Error in Safari

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I added a recaptcha script on my Netsuite external form and it works on every browser except for Safari (using 5.1.7).

It gives this error:
"onSubmit (saveRecord) customform JS_EXCEPTION ReferenceError Can't find variable: onSubmit"

The code I'm using is below and the Safari error console doesn't give me anything. Any ideas?

```
function onSubmit() {
  var captchaChallenge = $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(); 
  var captchaResponse = $('#recaptcha_response_field').val();

  var isToBeSubmitted = true; 

$.ajax({
  url: CAPTCHA_VERIFICATION_SUITELET_URL + '&challenge=' + captchaChallenge + '&response=' + captchaResponse,
  type: 'POST',
  accepts: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,

  async: false
  }).done(function (data) {
  if (!data.status.isSuccess) {
     alert('Captcha Verification Failed.');
     Recaptcha.reload();
     isToBeSubmitted = false;
  }
  });

  return isToBeSubmitted;
}
```

Images of script setup

[image][image]

Comment: Can you send us a screenshot of your Script setup in NetSuite?

Comment: Just added the screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue. When I attach a script to the online customer form, I needed to make sure the checkbox "Available Without Login" is checked. Never saw it before, but I checked it and it solved the issue with Safari. Attached a picture for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the function to another name not so generic like

```
function onCustomerSubmit
```